# Javascript Comparison for string of dots

Tags: javascript

May be a silly issue i am facing but code

```
if(colValue!="…")
            {
                alert("hi");
            }
```

giving me alert although value of colValue is `…`

Any workaround?

Comment: why not to use regular expression something like `/[\.+]/`

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: what is the output of alert(typeof colValue) ?

Comment: Now I have tried it in the Chrome31, FF26 and IE10. Works in all of them.

Comment: I've checked in Chrome and the code works. Need to show how you are setting `colValue`

Comment: "..." or "…" ? You told Sarath "..." but your code and comments to answers seem to indicate "…".

Comment: Note: You need to use your mouse to highlight the strings to understand my comment above.

Comment: @slebetman From a comment from a now deleted answer it is clear that Aquarius24 want the ellipsis character.

Comment: I just rewrite my code and it's working now... may be some problem with the encoding .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gYbbQ/1/)

Its working fine, check for spaces in string:

```
var colValue = "…";
if (colValue != "…") {
    alert("hi");
} else {
    alert("not");
}
```

Comment: It is not full stop, it is Unicode U+2026, Latin entity &hellip;

Comment: OP is looking for the ellipsis character, not 3 dot characters in a row.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed When I downvoted you you where using full stop. Since you have edited your answer I have removed the downvote. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gYbbQ/